# How to edit external lists in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

I currently have a simple external content type that displays a very small sql table on a external list in my SharePoint site. The problem is I have a date of birth field that gets formatted with the `DateTime` type instead of the `Date` type that is used when I created the SQL table. The biggest issue I am facing is the lack of designer view in SharePoint Designer 2013 that was included in 2010. Since I am forced to work with the source code, how do I go about formatting the date of birth fields so that it is displayed in simple `Date` format example: `01/01/2001`. And also prevent the time from showing when adding or entering a new record to the list.

Comment: Yes, please, someone help with this. :) Exact same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SELECT LEFT`SQL statement to pull just the relevant information.  Are you familiar with this method?

For clarification, here's an example:

```
CDate(Left([FieldName],10)
```

While being sure to change [FieldName] to match the field's name in your table.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with that method, but I am trying to achieve a consistent `Date` format in all aspects of the external list not just when it reads but also when a user enters a new record and is asked for the date of birth. Currently when a user enters a new record or edits a new record through the site, it asks for date of birth `Date` as well as the `time`.